# How to reduce the response time of a query that yields ~4.9 million rows in ~12-13 seconds

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.5, query

I have the following doubt about the execution performance of a query. This query takes about 12-13 seconds, and brings a total of 4,879,049 rows. Could I lessen this query's response time?

The query at issue is the following one:

```
  SELECT id_empresa,
         referencia,
         archivo,
         status 
    FROM Outbound_call_files 
   WHERE movido=0 
     AND status NOT IN('Peticion') 
ORDER BY id_empresa, status;
```

The execution plan is:

```
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Outbound_call_files | ref  | motivo_status | motivo_status | 1       | const | 2561294 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------+-
```

SHOW CREATE INDEX returns the following:

```
| Outbound_call_files |          1 | motivo_status      |            1 | movido      | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Outbound_call_files |          1 | motivo_status      |            2 | id_empresa  | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Outbound_call_files |          1 | motivo_status      |            3 | status      | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

I can see the cardinality is too low.

The structure and constraints of this table are shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE `Outbound_call_files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_empresa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_campana` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `referencia` text NOT NULL,
  `movido` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `archivo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_empresa_campana` (`id_empresa`,`id_campana`),
  KEY `motivo_status` (`movido`,`id_empresa`,`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10144111 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Executing profiling, this was the result:

```
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
+----------------------+-----------+
| Status               | Duration  |
+----------------------+-----------+
| starting             |  0.000070 |
| checking permissions |  0.000008 |
| Opening tables       |  0.000019 |
| System lock          |  0.000010 |
| init                 |  0.000030 |
| optimizing           |  0.000018 |
| statistics           |  0.000090 |
| preparing            |  0.000022 |
| executing            |  0.000004 |
| Sorting result       |  0.000006 |
| Sending data         | 12.512944 |
| end                  |  0.000017 |
| query end            |  0.000006 |
| closing tables       |  0.000011 |
| freeing items        |  0.000019 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000004 |
| logging slow query   |  0.000067 |
| cleaning up          |  0.000006 |
+----------------------+-----------+
```

*Note*: The database server has 150G RAM and the buffer pool is configured in 100G.

Comment: What use case requires retrieving 4 million rows to the client? Please also consider formatting your question properly.

Comment: Im optimizing all slow queries into slow query log file and this query is one of them. I dont undestand logic behind from this query but as dba my dutty is optimize and improve the mess that the developers does

Comment: This query runs in Mysql 5.5.62, This table contains a total of ~ 5 millions of rows, RAM is 150G and the buffer pool is configured 100G

Comment: _"as dba my dutty is optimize and improve the mess"_ -- I think a DBA's duty is to _avoid_ the mess, not improve it. You'll need to keep developers in line when warranted, including this case. In my view there is no realistic use case requiring the client to pull ~5 million rows from the database. Also, now that the query profile is properly formatted, it is obvious that the network is your bottleneck, and there's nothing you can do about it on the database side.

Comment: totally i agree with you but if the mess was done before I was and now you were requested to correct the mess

Comment: If your bottleneck is network then the solution is to reduce the data size being sent or increase the pipe size. There's no magic trick to circumvent this.

Comment: What are the possible value of `status`?  How many of each?  `SELECT status, count(*) FROM Outbound_call_files GROUP BY status;`

Comment: What do you do with the 4.8M rows?  I ask because maybe you could do more with it _before_ getting to the client.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new index that is based on movido,status, id_empresa, referencia, archivo

To convert the query to a covering index